# How can I retain inactive users for the stored procedure below

Tags: mysql

Im trying to retain the data from inactive users from the past 12 months
And im getting a syntax error 1064:

> near 'IFNULL(ub.updated_at, ub.inserted_at) < ( CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), "_", MONTH(NOW())' at line 2 .

Here's the sample stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE `logdb_user_breaks_delete`(

IN log_database VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4, 

IN retention_logdb INT(11) )

BEGIN SET @v = concat('DELETE FROM `',log_database ,'`.`user_breaks` ub WHERE

IFNULL(ub.updated_at, ub.inserted_at) < (CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), "-", MONTH(NOW()), "-

", "01") - INTERVAL ',retention_logdb,' MONTH);');

PREPARE stm FROM @v;

EXECUTE stm; 

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Im doing it in heidi sql version 10

Here's how I call the stored procedure :

CALL procedure_name(db_name,12);

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you really have a line break after the `-` in `"-"`? Instead of `(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), "-", MONTH(NOW()), "-", "01")` you can use `FORMAT_DATE(NOW(), "%Y-%m-01")`

Comment: Oh it's supposed to be " - "  like this .Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Also im not sure where to put the active=0 in the where clause so I can only retain data from inactive users only

Comment: By the way I edited my question and the codes above is finally working but it retains all of the users i only need to retain  the inactive ones .Thanks

Comment: No fair editing the question after I answered the original question. If you have a different problem, post a new question.

Comment: Just add `AND active = 0`

Comment: I mean it is the same question I just removed the syntax error  but same context though .

Comment: The original question was about the syntax error, I showed how to fix that in my answer. You didn't fix that problem when you edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until MySQL 8.0, single-table `DELETE` statements cannot assign an alias to the table name. So remove the `ub` alias.

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE `logdb_user_breaks_delete`(IN log_database VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4, IN retention_logdb INT(11) )

BEGIN
    SET @v = concat('DELETE FROM `',log_database ,'`.`user_breaks` WHERE
IFNULL(updated_at, inserted_at) < (CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), "-", MONTH(NOW()), "-", "01") - INTERVAL ', retention_logdb, ' MONTH);');

    PREPARE stm FROM @v;
    EXECUTE stm;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```